# Change size of the media:thumbnail on Blogger RSS Feed

Tags: javascript, rss, blogger

Is there any way to resize the media:thumbnail URL on the RSS feed(Blogger)  At the moment it's at the default size of height 72px and width 72px.
I have tried adding this javascript on the Template and didn't manage to get it work- I added it just before `</body>`

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function resizeThumb(e,b){var c=document.getElementById(e),d=c.getElementsByTagName("img");for(var a=0;a<d.length;a++){d[a].src=d[a].src.replace(/\/s72\-c/,"/s"+b+"-c");d[a].width=b;d[a].height=b}}resizeThumb("ID,100 );//]]>

</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how i did it:

```
  $img = el.find("thumbnail").attr("url");  //Get thumnail image from rss feed
  $newText = $img.replace(/\/s72\-c/, "");//replace /s72\-c with nothing
  console.log($newText);
```