# Change size of media:thumbnail on Blogger RSS Feed

Tags: javascript, rss, blogger

I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090172/change-size-of-the-mediathumbnail-on-blogger-rss-feed) post exists but it seems in those 4 years there have been updates to how bloggers thumbnails are generated.
I've tried several approaches, but none of them work so if anyone could help me to find a solution for my problem I'd really appreciate it.

I'd like to change the thumbnail size of my blogger posts that RSS feed grabs.
Right now it's using the **s72-c** (72x72) sized version of my blogger posts and I'd like to **replace those with the s1600 version**.

In theory it should be simple, but I can't get it to work.

I've tried

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$img = el.find("thumbnail").attr("url");  //Get thumnail image from rss feed
$newText = $img.replace(/\/s72-c/, /\/s1600/);  //replace /s72-c with s1600
console.log($newText);
</script>
```

and

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {$(".post-thumb").attr("src", function(i, src) {return src.replace( "s72-c", "s1600" );});});
</script>
```

Another workaround could also be to replace the s72-c part in my zapier code, before it's making the notification post on discord, but fixing the issue at it's core would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(img) {
    img.src = img.src.replace('/s72-c','/s1600');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, blogger is running on xml, so do you think I have to add it in my <head> or <body> ?

Comment: You are welcome. This code works only after images. So place it at the bottom before </body>